# How to terminate using getline()

Tags: c++, string, file-io, getline, stringtokenizer

I am trying to store some integers in a file and I am storing it with ',' as delimiter. Now when I read the file, I read the line using getline() and use tokenizer to delimit the file, However, I cannot terminate the line, I need some bool condition in getline to terminate.

```
 while(getline(read,line)) {
         std::cout<<line<<std::endl;
         std::istringstream tokenizer(line);
         std::string token;
         int value;

         while(????CONDN???) {
                 getline(tokenizer,token,',');
                 std::istringstream int_value(token);
                 int_value>>value;
                 std::cout<<value<<std::endl;
         }
  }
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it is enough to use `getline` in the same way as you do in the outer loop:

```
while(getline(tokenizer, token, ','))
```

While most likely I'd do something like this:

```
while(std::getline(read,line)) { // read line by line
     std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ',', ' ' ); // get rid of commas
     std::istringstream tokenizer(line);
     int number;

     while(tokenizer >> number) // read the ints
         std::cout<<number<<std::endl;
}
```

And two other alternatives - that use Boost.

[String Algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3184031):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
...
std::vector<std::string> strings;
boost::split(strings, "1,3,4,5,6,2", boost::is_any_of(","));
```

or [tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html):

```
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
typedef boost::char_separator<char> separator_t;
typedef boost::tokenizer<separator_t> tokenizer_t;
...
tokenizer_t tokens(line, sep);
for(tokenizer_t::iterator it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

If you expect to encounter non-`int`, non-separator characters, e.g. `1 3 2 XXXX 4`. Then you'll have to decide what to do in such a case. `tokenizer >> number` will stop at something that is not an `int` and the `istringstream` error flags will be set. [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) is also your friend:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
...
try 
{
    int x = boost::lexical_cast<int>( "1a23" );
} 
catch(const boost::bad_lexical_cast &)
{
    std::cout << "Error: input string was not valid" << std::endl;
}
```

Finally, in C++11 you have the [stoi/stol/stoll](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string test = "1234";
    std::cout << std::stoi(str) << std::endl;
}
```